# error MSB4018: The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly on build server

Tags: .net, msbuild, teamcity, clickonce, build-server

I have a clickonce solution that works on several developer machines with VS 2015 installed. However, it doesn't work on our buildserver it comes with this signFile error. I have installed

- Build Tools 2015 update 3
- .Net 4.6.2 SDK
- Windows Software Development Kit

But apparantly the path to the signtool.exe isn't correctly setup. If I disable signing of manifest it will continue on, but come up with a setup.bin missing error.

Do anyone have a good clue how to solve the SignFile problem ?

```
[_DeploymentComputeClickOnceManifestInfo] Using "SignFile" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
[_DeploymentComputeClickOnceManifestInfo] SignFile
[SignFile] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3616, 5): error MSB4018: The "SignFile" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2, String path3)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.GetPathToTool(ResourceManager resources)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignPEFile(X509Certificate2 cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path, ResourceManager resources, Boolean useSha256)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFileInternal(X509Certificate2 cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path, Boolean targetFrameworkSupportsSha256, ResourceManager resources)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(X509Certificate2 cert, Uri timestampUrl, String path)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities.SignFile(String certThumbprint, Uri timestampUrl, String path, String targetFrameworkVersion)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.SignFile.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is being thrown on [line 195](https://github.com/rashiph/DecompliedDotNetLibraries/blob/master/Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0/Microsoft/Build/Tasks/Deployment/ManifestUtilities/SecurityUtilities.cs#L195) of `Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Deployment.ManifestUtilities.SecurityUtilities`, which is in the following method:

```
    internal static string GetPathToTool()
    {
        string pathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile(ToolName(), TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.Version35);
        if (pathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile == null)
        {
            pathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, ToolName());
        }
        if (!File.Exists(pathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile))
        {
            pathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile = null;
        }
        return pathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile;
    }
```

The immediate cause was that `Environment.CurrentDirectory` returned `null`, but the more salient one was that `ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkSdkFile(ToolName(), TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.Version35)` also returned `null`.

The above code is a only snapshot of a particular version of the class, but the hardcoded enum value `TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.Version35` tells me that the problem is that *Build Tools 2015 update 3* depends on a version of the .Net SDK other than 4.6.2.

**UPDATE:**

To help identify the specific SDK version, I pulled down the source code from the Update 3 release at https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/releases.

```
    internal static string GetPathToTool(System.Resources.ResourceManager resources)
    {
#pragma warning disable 618 // Disabling warning on using internal ToolLocationHelper API. At some point we should migrate this.
        string toolPath = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToWindowsSdkFile(ToolName, TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.VersionLatest, VisualStudioVersion.VersionLatest);
        if (toolPath == null)
            toolPath = ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToWindowsSdkFile(ToolName, TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.Version45, VisualStudioVersion.Version110);
        if (toolPath == null)
            toolPath = Path.Combine(ToolLocationHelper.GetPathToDotNetFrameworkSdk(TargetDotNetFrameworkVersion.Version40, VisualStudioVersion.Version100), "bin", ToolName);
        if (toolPath == null)
            toolPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), ToolName);
        if (!File.Exists(toolPath))
            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, resources.GetString("SecurityUtil.SigntoolNotFound"), toolPath));
        return toolPath;
#pragma warning restore 618
    }
```

Digging further into the solution, I determined that the latest release of Build Tools (the one you installed) does not include the [change](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/commit/20462155cc19be63ba9d6a1990e848c63b27a53e) to `Shared\FrameworkLocationHelper.cs` that added support for Framework 4.6.2. So to answer your follow-up question, **installing the 4.6.1 SDK should do the trick**.

**UPDATE 2:**

The OP identified an alternative solution: explicitly setting the value of the `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory` property, e.g. by adding `/p:TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory=PATH TO SIGNTOOL.EXE(?)` as an argument when invoking `msbuild.exe` from the command line.

Comment: I don't know how you figured this out, but thanks. Do you by any chance know which SDK it is dependent on, so I don't need to install all ? Right now I have circumvented this by setting the property /property:TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory when calling msbuild.

Comment: Answer updated with this info (I hope I am right!). As to how I figured this out, I started by going to the file and line number referenced near the top of your error log. When I saw that the `SignFile` task did not take a parameter for a path to a tool/executable, I knew I would need to see source code for the `SignFile` task. Luckily, MSBuild is now open source!

Comment: @dennis_ler - I have added your `TargetFrameworkSDKToolsDirectory` fix to this answer.